# How do I make an elegant API request with a large list of values in Python?

Tags: python, json, list, api

I'm writing Python code for a data server that downloads a vendor's entire product code list via an API call, checks inventory levels for each item in four different warehouses (another API call), and saves the results to a csv file.  Getting inventory levels for the products can happen in batches of up to 100 which is what I want to do.

The below code is super slow but just for reference, here's what I have if it's a single part that I'm doing the API request for:

```
def inventory_query(part_number):  # get inventory levels for each code
    try:
        api_config = read_config()["API"]
        host = api_config["host"]
        key = api_config["key"]

        url = "https://**********/api3/1/inventory"

        headers = {
            "X-API-HOST": host,
            "X-API-KEY": key
        }

        data = {
            "productCodes": [
                part_number
            ],
            "warehouseCodes": [
                "1000",
                "1100",
                "1200",
                "1300"
            ]
        }

        response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
        text = soup.get_text(separator='\n').split('\n')

        return str(text[0]), str(text[6]), str(text[3]), str(text[9])
        
    except ConnectionResetError:
        time_now = datetime.now()
        logging.debug(str(time_now) + " - Couldn't get inventory levels!")
```

Request data with two product codes:

```
{
  "productCodes": [
    "BB0698",
    "BB0544"
  ],
  "warehouseCodes": [
    "1000",  
    "1100",  
    "1200",
    "1300"
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
<InventoryResponse>
    <responseStatus type="OK"/>
    <errors/>
    <inventories>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>0</quantity>
            <product>BB0544</product>
            <warehouse>1000</warehouse>
        </inventory>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>0</quantity>
            <product>BB0544</product>
            <warehouse>1100</warehouse>
        </inventory>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>40</quantity>
            <product>BB0544</product>
            <warehouse>1200</warehouse>
        </inventory>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>50</quantity>
            <product>BB0544</product>
            <warehouse>1300</warehouse>
        </inventory>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>4</quantity>
            <product>BB0698</product>
            <warehouse>1000</warehouse>
        </inventory>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <product>BB0698</product>
            <warehouse>1100</warehouse>
        </inventory>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>3</quantity>
            <product>BB0698</product>
            <warehouse>1200</warehouse>
        </inventory>
        <inventory>
            <quantity>3</quantity>
            <product>BB0698</product>
            <warehouse>1300</warehouse>
        </inventory>
    </inventories>
</InventoryResponse>
```

I feel there's a better way than making a list of 100 codes at a time (named "parts") and replacing `part_number` with `str(parts[0]), str(parts[1]), str(parts[2]), etc...`  to the POST data.

Is there an efficient way to handle this API request?  I can get away with doing

`part1 = str(text[12]), str(text[18]), str(text[15]), str(text[21])`

`part2 = str(text[0]), str(text[6]), str(text[3]), str(text[9])`

but that's 100 part variables I need to create.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some examples of `parts`? And is your limiting factor sending a lot of requests? Or do you want to know how to create your parameter-data and send it all in one request?

Comment: Sounds like you might find some sort of list comprehension relevant, like `','.join([str(x) for x in parts[:100]])`, but as bitflip says, we need a little more info to provide a good recommendation.

Comment: @bitflip `parts` would be something like `['BB0129', 'BB0130', 'CK2145']` but 100 product codes.  My limiting factor is that getting inventory levels for each code individually takes way, way, way too long so I need to get inventory levels in batches of 100 codes at once (which is what the documentation recommends).

Comment: @DraftyHat I edited my question so it made more sense.  I just want to know if there's any elegant way to handle 100 product codes both in the request data and json response. i.e. not having to write ```str(parts[0]), str(parts[1]), str(parts[2]), etc....``` under ```productCodes```